# Client Error Exception's message in try except case

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

Hey I know I can do try except to resolve ClientError warning but is there any way that exception could be more precise meaning instead of `except ClientError:` Can I do `except InvalidPermission.Duplicate:`

This is the complete output I am getting without applying any exceptions:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidPermission.Duplicate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get error code like this -

using this-

```
try:
    boto3_api_operation()
except ClientError as e:
    code = e.response["Error"]["Code"]
    print(code)
    #O/p - InvalidPermission.Duplicate
```

You can read [AWS Error Codes Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/errors-overview.html)

Let me know,if it helps!

Comment: @Ahsan , please upvote this answer if you find it useful and marked it if if helps you achieving what you find . thanks